# no visible interface for 'GAITransaction'

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, in-app-purchase, tracking

I'm trying to implement In app purchase tracking in iOS with Google Analytics but I receive these errors:

The exact example code taken from the Google Analytics page has 2 errors:

```
- (void)onPurchaseCompleted {
  GAITransaction *transaction =
  [GAITransaction transactionWithId:@"0_123456"            // (NSString) Transaction ID, should be unique.
                    withAffiliation:@"In-App Store";       // (NSString) Affiliation
```

When I compile here above it says a "]" to be inserted

```
   transaction.taxMicros = (int64_t)(0.17 * 1000000);           // (int64_t) Total tax (in micros)
  transaction.shippingMicros = (int64_t)(0);                   // (int64_t) Total shipping (in micros)
  transaction.revenueMicros = (int64_t)(2.16 * 1000000);       // (int64_t) Total revenue (in micros)
```

Here below I get this error: "no visible interface for 'GAITransaction' declares the selector 'addItemWithSKU:name:category:priceMicros:quantity'"

```
  [transaction addItemWithSKU:@"L_789"                         // (NSString) Product SKU
                     name:@"Level Pack: Space"             // (NSString) Product name
                 category:@"Game expansions"               // (NSString) Product category
              priceMicros:(int64_t)(1.99 * 1000000)        // (int64_t)  Product price (in micros)
                 quantity:1];                              // (NSInteger)  Product quantity

   [[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker sendTransaction:transaction]; // Send the transaction.
   }
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Error 1: Yes, the code you pasted does not have a square bracket at the end, add it before the semicolon and the error will go away.

Error 2:

> no visible interface for 'GAITransaction' declares the selector
>   'addItemWithSKU:name:category:priceMicros:quantity'

That means that your `transaction` instance does not respond to the `addItemWithSKU:name:category:priceMicros:quantity` method. Did you import the required files? Is there a `addItemWithSKU:name:category:priceMicros:quantity` method signature in your .h file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using the latest Doc. [Try this one.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/ecommerce)